# Execute all the document.ready handlers, those are loaded in ajax

Tags: ajax, document-ready

I have a scenario where I need to load a HTML page(which may have some script in it) through an ajax request.

We might have few $(document).ready handlers in the actual page rendered, that have got already executed on current document's ready though. Now when ajax response is loaded onto the document, then i need all those document.ready handlers within the ajax-response to be executed.

The script that is getting loaded via ajax is not in our control to modify!

So, is there any way to deal with this kind of situation?

Thanks in advance,
SuryaPavan

Answer (score 0):

change the dataType to html to make it execute.

"html": Returns HTML as plain text; included script tags are evaluated when inserted in the DOM.